# 360 degrees rotating view in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Are there any good JavaScript libraries that can do this ?

These are usually done in flash

I have found this plugin so far, looking for others to evaluate.

http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel

Comment: Ehmmm... "360 degrees rotation" amounts to  "no rotation". You mean a rotation by an arbitrary angle (0-360) ?

Comment: just to clear things up.  I have a sequence of photos taken around an object.

Check out the link in my post to see what i mean.

Comment: i guess that is a bad title, i want to rotate the view

Comment: Ah, yes, it would rather be "360 degrees view" or "360 degrees rotating view"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try these!

> - http://www.mathieusavard.info/threesixty/demo.html
> - http://www.silverscripting.com/pamoorama/sample1.html
> - http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery.panorama/

Comment: first link is the kind of thing im after.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an X degree rotation thing, we used this script from TwitPic (http://twitpic.com/1kg9w8). It was very easy to adapt. If you want some spinning thing, I guess you could combine this library with a timeout to have it move at intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one?
http://lukedurrant.com/2011/08/apples-360-rotating-ipod-html-5-source-code-download/