# Javascript library for room 3d presentation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need cross browser 3d js library allows me to present 3d room interior. Any suggestions/examples?

Comment: I have made it in flash. I didn't tried in javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755472/360-degrees-rotating-view-in-javascript

Comment: then I'm posting this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most used library for 3D client-side rendering is [three.js](http://threejs.org/) but this will require a bit of programming.

As already stated in the comments, here you may find some solutions which are more suitable for your needs and require less code from you: [360 degrees rotating view in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755472/360-degrees-rotating-view-in-javascript)

Comment: three.js requires webgl so it's not good solution because user must to install it

Comment: wrong - three.js may be used with canvas render and work on non-webgl browsers. WebGL is required for more advanced features but you can create a cube and project some textures over it without using WebGL rendering.

Comment: three.js canvas render fallback: http://japhr.blogspot.it/2012/07/fallback-from-webgl-to-canvas-in-threejs.html